# Uploaded image in angular 7 not displayed just after upload

Tags: javascript, angular, filereader

I have written the below code which is working, there is no compilation error. I am successfully getting the uploaded images printed in the console. But just after uploading the image, its not visible in the page. I need to click anywhere on the screen ,then the images get previewed in the screen.

```js
  onFileChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
     var filesAmount = event.target.files.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]); 
        reader.onload = (event: any) => {
            this.images.push(event.target.result);           
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
 <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
      <section>
        <h3 class="fs-20 fw-600 text-color9 mb-30">
          Step 4: Sample information
        </h3>
        <div class="samples d-flex flex-wrap mb-5">
          <div class="sample-item mb-3 mb-lg-0">
            <div
              class="upload-box rounded-4 bg-white position-relative d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column overflow-hidden"
            >
              <input
                id="file"
                type="file"
                class="form-control"
                accept="image/*"
                (change)="onFileChange($event)"
              />

              <i class="icon-plus fs-36 text-color4 mb-2"></i>
              <h6 class="fs-18 fw-500 text-color4 mb-0">Upload image</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sample-item mb-3 mb-lg-0">
            <div class="image-box">
              <img class="rounded-4" *ngFor="let url of images" [src]="url" />
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

//other formgoup inputs will be written here

        <div class="action-button pb-3">
          <hr />
          <div class="text-end">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-sm btn-primary-outline me-3"
              routerLink="/order/create-order"
              [queryParams]="{ id: orderObject?.orderID }"
            >
              Back
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
              Continue
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </form>
```

Every time I click choose file in the `this.image` the images get inserted. If I try to run`console.log(this.images)`  it also gets printed . But its not immediately rendered in the screen by this array `this.images` via `*ngFor`

When this ts code is run in [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts](https://here) its running fine. Just after choosing file the image get visible in the screen.

Please help me to know what is the reason behind such behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to run the angular cycle again. try

```
 constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

 reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.images.push(event.target.result);  
      this.cdr.detectChanges();         
  };
```